Can i reuse CloudBuild files?
I am currently working with GCP on a project involving 40 programs that need to be deployed on Cloud Run. For CI/CD, I will use Cloud Build and SonarQube for code quality. I don't want to write 40 Cloud Build files with the same command to execute the SonarQube scanner because if I need to change that command for any reason, I would have to repeat the same process 39 more times.
Is there a way to reuse steps between Cloud Build files?
Thanks for your time.
I was thinking of creating a Docker image that runs the SonarQube scanner and reusing that image in all Cloud Build files.

Good question, and I would say  "no you can't". You can have a central file, that you can reference in your CLoud Build command, and provide the correct substitution variable. But you can't perform includes like Gitlab CI for instance.
